# system font size in UWP?

Tags: uwp, font-size

I have a cross-platform app. The app internally figures out all its font sizes relative to a system-provided base size. On iOS I get this by calling

```
return UIFont.SystemFontSize;
```

and on Mac, I get it by calling

```
return NSFont.SystemFontSize;
```

On Android, I have to fudge something up using the screen dpi.

Does uwp provide a system font size? Or do I need to fudge something up there, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UWP doesn't have a single pre-defined fontsize on which everything is based, but rather a list of font sizes defined in [generic.xaml](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/how-to-change-a-default-style-or-color-of-a-standard-control) (where all default controls their styles live).

Grabbing some of the sizes out of that file:

```
<x:Double x:Key="ControlContentThemeFontSize">15</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">15</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TextStyleLargeFontSize">18.14</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize">25.5</x:Double>
```

If you look at the controls, you'll notice that the `ControlContentThemeFontSize` is the one used for most controls regular text size.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
...
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />

...
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
...
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
```

You can simply retrieve any key from the default resources with following code, this being a page/control/...:

```
this.Resources["ControlContentThemeFontSize"]
```

Comment: Any ideas how to override these values.  I want a smaller Content Control Font Size.